# How to use SQLAlchemy contextmanager and still get row ID?

Tags: python, transactions, sqlalchemy, contextmanager

I am using SQLAlchemy's [provided `contextmanager`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#session-frequently-asked-questions) to handle sessions for me. What I don't understand is how to get the automatically generated ID because (1) the ID is not created until after `commit()` is called yet (2) the newly created instance is only available in the context manager's scope:

```
def save_soft_file(name, is_geo=False):
    with session_scope() as session:
        soft_file = models.SoftFile(name=name, is_geo=is_geo)
        session.add(soft_file)
        # id is not available here, because the session has not been committed
    # soft_file is not available here, because the session is out of context
    return soft_file.id
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`session.flush()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html?highlight=session#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.flush) to execute pending commands within the current transaction.

```
def save_soft_file(name, is_geo=False):
    with session_scope() as session:
        soft_file = models.SoftFile(name=name, is_geo=is_geo)
        session.add(soft_file)
        session.flush()
        return soft_file.id
```

If an exception occurs after a `flush` but before the session goes out of scope, the changes will be rolled back to the beginning of the transaction. In that case your `soft_file` would not actually be written to the database, even though it had been given an ID.